# Parentheses Balancing functions in scala

Tags: scala

I have written a function to balance parentheses, but i have encountered some problems

```
def subfunc(left: Int, chars: List[Char]): Boolean = {
  if (chars.isEmpty) {
    if (left == 0) { println("true"); true }
    else false
  **} else {**
    if (chars.head == '(') subfunc(left + 1, chars.tail)
    else if (chars.head == ')') {
      if (left > 0) subfunc(left - 1, chars.tail)
      else false
    } else
      subfunc(left, chars.tail)
  }
}
```

when func is like this, the perfermance is ok, but if I rm the **} else {**
and the code become this

```
  def subfunc(left: Int, chars: List[Char]): Boolean = {
    if (chars.isEmpty) {
      if (left == 0) { println("true"); true }
      else false
    }
    println("come to here")
    if (chars.head == '(') subfunc(left + 1, chars.tail)
    else if (chars.head == ')') {
      if (left > 0) subfunc(left - 1, chars.tail)
      else false
    } else
      subfunc(left, chars.tail)
  }
```

and the test crash

```
  subfunc(0, chars)                               //> come to here?
                                                  //| come to here?
                                                  //| come to here?
                                                  //| come to here?
                                                  //| come to here?
                                                  //| true
                                                  //| come to here?
                                                  //| java.util.NoSuchElementException: head of empty list
                                                  //|   at scala.collection.immutable.Nil$.head(List.scala:337)
                                                  //|   at scala.collection.immutable.Nil$.head(List.scala:334)
                                                  //|   at recfun.expriment$$anonfun$main$1.subfunc$1(recfun.expriment.scala:22)
                                                  //| 
                                                  //|   at recfun.expriment$$anonfun$main$1.apply$mcV$sp(recfun.expriment.scala:
                                                  //| 35)
                                                  //|   at org.scalaide.worksheet.runtime.library.WorksheetSupport$$anonfun$$exe
                                                  //| cute$1.apply$mcV$sp(WorksheetSupport.scala:76)
                                                  //|   at org.scalaide.worksheet.runtime.library.WorksheetSupport$.redirected(W
                                                  //| orksheetSupport.scala:65)
                                                  //|   at org.scalaide.worksheet.runtime.library.WorksheetSupport$.$execute(Wor
                                                  //| ksheetSupport.scala:75)
                                                  //|   at recfun.expriment$.main(recfun.expriment.scala:3)
                                                  //|   at recfun.expriment.main(recfun.expriment.scala)
```

it seems that the program comes to subfunc(0, emptylist)
but why it print "come to here" after the line

```
if (left == 0) { println("true"); true}
```

is executed ?

Comment: Because your first `if` is just swallowed -- `if (..) else ..; if (..) else ...` -- when you write code like this, both if's are executed, but result of the first one is ignored and code flow proceeds to the next `if` (no matter if list empty or not -- as I said, first check is ignored).

Answer (score 1):

Because scala return only on last function *expression*.
Your first code is analogous to *return result of either branch of `if(chars.isEmpty)`*. Your second code is analogous to *execute first if, then return result of either branch of `chars.head == '('.`*. That's it -- when you write code this way function **does not return eagerly** after the first if.